# How to delete random items in a list to keep the list in a certain length?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, random

I used **pymongo** to dump a list of collections in MongoDB. The length of the list is greater than 10000, about 12000 or longer(The length of the list is not a certain number).

However, I need only 10000 instances of the list. I know that a list **'l'** is able to slice by `l[:10000]` or `l[len(l)-10000:]`. But I think maybe a random way to delete the item in a list is better.

So I want to know how can I delete random items in the list to make its length reduce to 10000 long? Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that randomly deleting elements is very bad for testability. You might want to consider deleting every nth element or just shaving off the top few.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shuffle the list first and then slice it:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(your_lis)
your_lis = your_lis[:10000]
```

If order matters:

```
from random import randrange
diff = len(your_lis) - 10000
for _ in xrange(diff):
    ind = randrange(len(your_lis))
    your_lis.pop(ind)  #a quick timing check suggests that `pop` is faster than `del`
```

Comment: Thanks, the list order doesn't matter. And I write a test script, the first one uses 0.01 seconds and the second is 0.08 seconds. Why the latter one is much slower?

Comment: @zfz slicing is faster than a for-loop.

Comment: @zfz plus `pop` and `del` operations are expensive.

Comment: @zfz glad that helped, you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep order, you can remove random indexes, for instance:

```
def remove_random(l, count):
    for i in range(count):
        index = random.randint(0, len(l) - 1)
        del l[index]
```

This function will remove up to `count` items from list `l`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
from random import random

def chop(the_list, length):
    while len(the_list) > length:
        del the_list[int(random()*length)]

# usage
chop(your_list, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite straightforward using numpy (only extracting 4 items for readability):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = range(0, 12000)
>>> np.random.choice(np.asarray(l), 4, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def random_reduce(list, count):
    length = len(l)
    for i in range(count):
        index = random.randint(0, length - 1)
        del list[index]
        length = length - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

subsample=random.sample(population,k)
```

Comment: Worth noting that `k` should be `len(original_list) - number_of_items_to_delete` for this to answer the question...